# Connection to Azure Storage Analytics via C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343262.aspx as a reference.

That page says

```
"The $logs container is located in the blob namespace of the storage account, 
for example: http://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/$logs"
```

And further on it says

```
"you can use the ListBlobs method to access the blobs in the $logs container."
```

Now on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee772878.aspx it gives an example:

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = 
    new CloudBlobClient(blobEndpoint, 
                        new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("accountName", "key"));

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myblobs");
```

Question: If the blobs are stored at http://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/$logs then what do I make the blobEndPoint?

What do I put as the GetContainerReference("") ? I do not know the name of the container, I am new to Azure.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I put as the GetContainerReference("") ?

You would put `$logs` there. so your code would be:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("$logs");
```

Following screenshot shows how the blobs are stored in `$logs` directory

[image]

Essentially it is `$logs / [blob|queue|table] / YYYY / MM / DD / HH00 / blob file`. The blob file is a sequential file of `6 characters length` starting from `000000`. Since you don't know the name of the blob, I would recommend that you do a `List Blobs` operation first to get all the blobs. To limit the number of blobs, you could do a `prefix` based search as well. For example, let's say you want to find all log entries for `blobs` for `2013-08-15` you would need to pass `blob/2013/08/15` as blob prefix when you are listing blobs.

**UPDATE:**

However, please note that storage analytics are not enabled by default. You would need to enable it first. The screenshot I pasted below is from `Azure Management Studio` from Cerebrata (http://www.cerebrata.com). You can use that tool to enable storage analytics. They also have a free tool to configure analytics which you can download from here: http://blog.cerebrata.com/articles/2011/08/11/cerebrata-windows-azure-storage-analytics-configuration-utility-a-free-utility-to-configure-windows-azure-storage-analytics/. First, please enable storage analytics, wait for sometime for this container to get created and then execute your code.

Comment: Thanks - I tried the following: CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("$logs"); and when I tried to call container.ListBlobs() I got an exception saying the container does not exist. How can I see which containers do exist?

Comment: Ahh, I see. I think you have not enabled storage analytics. You would need to do that first. Please see my updated response. HTH.

Comment: One last thing Gaurav - how do I query the blobs based on metadata such as StartTime, EndTime, LogType? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343262.aspx says you can query but does not say how

Comment: I looked at the link and I don't think it is right. To the best of my knowledge, blob metadata is not queryable i.e. you can't fetch the blobs based on Metadata. Let me find more about it.

Comment: Here's what I heard back: `You can’t filter on a metadata value. What the below I believe is intended to mean is that when you list the blobs you can get the metadata as part of the listing.  The metadata will tell you the time range of the logs in each blog.  You can then use this information to decide which blobs you want to look in for a particular time frame for the given hour.` HTH.